# Apply plugin configuration in init.gradle script

Tags: gradle, init, gradle-plugin

I want to install some packages locally for all my projects, e.g. dependency-analyse. But I need to actually configure the plugin - also in the init script.

```
initscript {
    repositories {
      jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
      classpath "ca.cutterslade.gradle:gradle-dependency-analyze:1.3.0"
    }
}
allprojects {
  apply plugin: ca.cutterslade.gradle.analyze.AnalyzeDependenciesPlugin
}
```

This init script works fine and applies the plugin, but unfortunately, the default setting is that the plugin fails the build. I would like to just log a warning.

For that I need to add configs:

```
analyzeClassesDependencies {
  justWarn = true
}

analyzeTestClassesDependencies {
  justWarn = true
}
```

but when I try to add it in the init.gradle file:

```
initscript {
    repositories {
      jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
      classpath "ca.cutterslade.gradle:gradle-dependency-analyze:1.3.0"
    }
}
allprojects {
  apply plugin: ca.cutterslade.gradle.analyze.AnalyzeDependenciesPlugin
  analyzeClassesDependencies {
    justWarn = true
  }

  analyzeTestClassesDependencies {
    justWarn = true
  }
}
```

I get an error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Initialization script '/Users/<my-user>/.gradle/init.gradle' line: 13

* What went wrong:
Could not find method analyzeClassesDependencies() for arguments [init_2y9p9if69e8553k9fsvzz4a28$_run_closure1$_closure2@3e17c37a] on root project 'my-project' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

Anybody an idea of how I can apply plugin configuration?
I tried the [gradle forum](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/apply-plugin-configuration-in-init-gradle-script/32015) but didn't get any answer, so I hope to get some more help here :)

Comment: there is also an error in the `initscript` block (maybe just a copy/paste from your project):  the `dependencies` block is inside an additional/unwanted `repositories` block

Comment: @M.Ricciuti thanks, yes that is a copy-paste error, sorry

Comment: Ok. the real issue is explained in my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AnalyzeDependenciesPlugin` will add different tasks depending on which plugin is applied to your project. For example `analyzeClassesDependencies` and `analyzeTestClassesDependencies` will be declared only when `java` plugin is applied (see how this plugin is implemented here : https://github.com/wfhartford/gradle-dependency-analyze/blob/master/src/main/groovy/ca/cutterslade/gradle/analyze/AnalyzeDependenciesPlugin.groovy )

So you just need to apply `java` plugin before you apply the `AnalyzeDependenciesPlugin` in your `allprojects` configuration closure:

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: "java" // <= apply Java plugin here
    apply plugin: ca.cutterslade.gradle.analyze.AnalyzeDependenciesPlugin
    analyzeClassesDependencies {
        justWarn = true
    }
    analyzeTestClassesDependencies {
        justWarn = true
    }
}
```